# Initialize multiple instances of database for two environments

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android app which is based on Apartments/Societies needs. I have used Firebase to store all data of the Users. I have created multiple instances of database. Like one instance for Society A, another instance for Society B and so on. I have also configured two environment for my project, 'DEV' and 'BETA'. But I am unable to initialize the instances of database for both environments. Like I want instance of Society A in both DEV and BETA. Right now I am able to initialize only one instance for one environment at a time.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access your second app, you need to pass in to the `getInstance()` method the name you set for the second app and then pass that in the request for the database instance like in the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondAppName");
FirebaseDatabase secondDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp);
```

To access the first app, simply use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Without passing anything to the `getInstance()` method.